# OCamlYaccやMenhirでコンフリクトを消す方法

Tags: ocaml

OCamlYaccやMenhirを使ったりするのですが、コンフリクトが発生した場合の解消はトライアンドエラーでなんとなく消しています。

何かツールの使い方やコツ等ご存知の方いましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 4):

YACC の shift/reduce, reduce/reduce conflict の解消はパーサーの教科書もしくはネット情報に沢山書かれているます。まず、YACC の基本動作原理とともにそれなりに理解してください。たとえば http://guppy.eng.kagawa-u.ac.jp/2006/ProgLang/bison-1.2.8/bison-ja_8.html など。

どの教科書にもありますが、だいたい、

- ルールが大雑把過ぎるのが原因であることが多いので、ジェネレータが conflict で迷わないようになるまでルールを書き下す。
- トークンの優先順位と結合方向を指定することで適用可能なルールの数を減らす
- reduce/reduce は解消したほうがよい
- shift/reduce の場合は shift 優先なので、それで満足ならほっておく (ただしあなたの YACC 経験値は上がりません)

ことで解消します。どこを直すべきかは、各パーサジェネレータの conflict レポートをよく読む。これしかないと私は思います。

私は一般的なパーサの知識はあまりないので、ここからは OCaml 特定の情報のみを紹介します。

#### Menhir を使う

OCaml では、 OCamlYacc は古いのでもう使わない Menhir を使う。
そして、 `menhir --explain` を使ってどこに conflict があるかちゃんと理解する、くらいでしょうか。

#### Menhir のレポートの読み方

次の例を使って `<basename>.conflicts` の読み方を説明します。 Bison などのドキュメントで出て来る reduce/reduce の例に少し足したものです:

```
%token WORD
%token START

%start <int> statement

%%

statement:
  | START sequence { $2 }
  ;

sequence:
  | /* empty */ { 0 }
  | maybeword { $1 }
  | sequence WORD { $1 + $2 }
  ;

maybeword:
  | /* empty */ { 0 }
  | WORD { 1 }
  ;

%%
```

上のコードを `menhir --explain x.mly` とすると次のような `x.conflicts` ファイルが出来ます。`.conflicts` ファイルは `** Conflict (...) in state XXX.` というラインから始まる conflict の説明の集合からなっています。レポートを読んでいて、 `** Conflict (..)` が出てきた時は別の conflict の説明に移っていることに注意すると読み易い:

```
** Conflict (shift/reduce/reduce) in state 1.
** Tokens involved: WORD #
** The following explanations concentrate on token WORD.
** This state is reached from statement after reading:

START
```

WORD に対する処理回りで conflict が起っています。これは `statement` からはじめて `START` を読み込んだ後、発生します。shift/reduce と reduce/reduce が同時に起っているようですね。

```
** The derivations that appear below have the following common factor:
** (The question mark symbol (?) represents the spot where the derivations begin to differ.)

statement 
START sequence 
      (?)
```

Conflict を起こす複数の解釈は `statement` を `START sequence` だとする所までは共通ですが、そこから先、 `sequence` をどうするか、の所で発生しています。以下はそれぞれの解釈がどうなっているかの説明です

```
** In state 1, looking ahead at WORD, reducing production
** maybeword -> 
** is permitted because of the following sub-derivation:

sequence WORD // lookahead token appears
maybeword // lookahead token is inherited
.
```

先読みトークン `WORD` がある時、この `WORD` を消費せず、 reduce を行って `sequence` を得ることができます: 下から読むと、 `(空) -> maybeword -> sequence` という構成法。(さらに先読みトークンの `WORD` を消費すると `sequence WORD -> sequence` になりますね。) `.` はパーサが見ているところはここ、というマークです。

```
** In state 1, looking ahead at WORD, shifting is permitted
** because of the following sub-derivation:

maybeword 
. WORD
```

先読みトークン `WORD` がある時に、この `WORD` を shift で消費することで、下から `WORD -> maybeword -> sequence` という構成が可能。 `. WORD` は今パーサが居るところが `.` で `WORD` は先読みトークンです。

```
** In state 1, looking ahead at WORD, reducing production
** sequence -> 
** is permitted because of the following sub-derivation:

sequence WORD // lookahead token appears
.
```

先読みトークン `WORD` がある時に、この `WORD` を消費せずに reduce して `sequence`　が構成できる: 下から `(空) -> sequence`。（さらに先読みトークンの `WORD` と併せると `sequence WORD -> sequence` を構成できます。）

さて、conflict の解消はとにかく受理可能セットを(それが正しいと仮定して)そのまま保ったまま、
このように複数のルールの選択可能性をルールを変更したり優先順位を加えたりして狭めていく、
ということなのですが、とにかくこうしろ、という機械的な方法はないのではないでしょうか。
(あればそもそもパーサジェネレータが勝手に解消してくれるはずです。)
もうこれは conflict レポートをよく読んで原因理由を理解するのが一番かと思います。
何かコツがあれば私も知りたいところです。